# Fetching join date from mysql database and echoing it as a readable format

Tags: php, mysql, date, registration

I want to fetch the join date of users from my database and then echo it out into a readable format. Here's my code:

```
function date_registered($user_id) {
$sqldate = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT `date_registered` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = $user_id"));
$date = strtotime($sqldate['date_registered']);
return date("j F Y", $sql);}
```

and the echo:

```
echo    '<p>Joined: ' . date_registered($user_id) . '</p>';
```

However, when using this code it echoes out "1 January 1970" as the join date, instead of the 22nd of May 2015 that is stored in the database.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: What's the type of date_registered and what's an example value?

Comment: it's set to TIMESTAMP, example: 2015-05-22 00:00:00

Comment: Beware of SQL Injections: `$user_id=1 OR TRUE ORDER BY RAND(); TRUNCATE users`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `return date("j F Y", $date);` instead of `return date("j F Y", $sql);`.

Comment: Lol how did I miss that :P Thanks!